# Access List of json object in ajax response

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, gson

Maybe I have a similar question over but I can't get the proper keyword to this question so please bear with me.

I have this kind of data in may java class

```
List<String> listOne = some data list from the database
List<String> listTwo = another data list from the database
```

**I want first to send this two** `List` **as json object to the client so what I thought is this:**

Either

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
map.put( listOne );
map.put( listTwo );

return new Gson().toJson( map );
```

Or

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
list.add( listOne );
list.add( listTwo );

return new Gjson().toJson( map );
```

I don't know which is better. **The next thing I want to do is access this to the client side**

```
$.post( 'some url', someData : 'that requires to know which data will be fetched',
        function( data ) {
        // here how can I access the two list inside the list
        // or the list inside the map
        // i want to have a full control to the data 
        // example:
        //    Iterate the listOne on this $('#someId').append( listOne );
        //    Iterate the listTwo on this $('#anotherId').append( listTwo );

      }, json);
```

What is the way to properly do this? If my question is unclear please comment and I'll response accordingly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should fix your code to:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
map.put("listOne", listOne );
map.put("listTwo", listTwo );

return new Gson().toJson( map );
```

Secondly, you should use the `$.GetJSON()` function:

```
$.getJSON( 'some url', function( data ) {
   //Do something with data

});
```

You can then access the data directly with `data.listOne` and `data.listTwo`.